# How to add multiple values to specific key in yaml? Neplan related

Tags: linux, bash, networking, yq, netplan

I am trying to config IPv6 addresses in Linux and I struggle how am I suppose to add values to netplan's YAML file, here is the file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [155.128.134.198/23,'2002:18f0:b009:f84:5200:03ff:fdf7:d0c2/64']
      gateway4: 155.128.134.198
      nameservers:
        addresses: [108.61.10.10]
      routes:
      - to: 169.254.0.0/16
        via: 155.138.148.1
        metric: 100
```

And I would like to add IPv6 addresses at the key`addresses`, but keep those existing there. Is it possible to do through `yq` or somewhat simple in any other way, so I can do bash script from that? I haven't found any tool which is specific tool for netplan to be able to easily add addresses in the range. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To append from a shell script, it does appear possible with the newest version of [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.2.1).

I can append to it as follows:

```
$ yq e '.network.ethernets.ens3.addresses += "127.0.0.1/32"' myyaml.yml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [155.128.134.198/23, '2002:18f0:b009:f84:5200:03ff:fdf7:d0c2/64', 127.0.0.1/32]
      gateway4: 155.128.134.198
      nameservers:
        addresses: [108.61.10.10]
      routes:
        - to: 169.254.0.0/16
          via: 155.138.148.1
          metric: 100
```

Note this doesn't update the actual file, you can either pipe that output to a new file or use the `-i` flag to update it in place.

Comment: Yeah, but I really don't know how to do that, how to append more values to addresses, I am searchning on the internet for hours and cannot find anything. I would like to just call some command through bash, which would add lines to the key. If this would not be script it would be easy, however even through `AnyIP` it does not work as intended. @Grizzle

Comment: It looks like you can do this with `yq` but you need version 4. I've updated my answer above.